# Connecting to Virtual Channels using C# interop and Vanara.PInvoke

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, interop

Despite my best efforts, I am unable to connect to a given virtual channel through `WTSVirtualChannelOpenEx`.

Using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/using-terminal-services-virtual-channels) documentation, I have done the following:

1. Added a subkey to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\Addins` on the server
2. Added a subkey to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Default\Addins` on the client
3. Created the following client DLL

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <cchannel.h>
VOID VCAPITYPE ChannelInitEventFn(
   LPVOID pInitHandle,
   UINT event,
   LPVOID pData,
    UINT dataLength
)
{
}
VOID VCAPITYPE ChannelOpenEventFn(DWORD  openHandle,
                                             UINT   event,
                                             LPVOID pData,
                                             UINT32 dataLength,
                                             UINT32 totalLength,
                                             UINT32 dataFlags);

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BOOL VirtualChannelEntry(PCHANNEL_ENTRY_POINTS pEntryPoints)
{
    LPVOID pInitHandle = nullptr;
    CHANNEL_DEF pChannel[1];

    // Set the virtual channel name
    strcpy_s(pChannel[0].name, "test");

    // Call VirtualChannelInit
    UINT result = pEntryPoints->pVirtualChannelInit(&pInitHandle, pChannel, sizeof(pChannel), VIRTUAL_CHANNEL_VERSION_WIN2000, ChannelInitEventFn);
    if (result != CHANNEL_RC_OK)
    {
        // Error handling...
    }

    LPDWORD pOpenHandle = nullptr;
    UINT result2 = pEntryPoints->pVirtualChannelOpen(pInitHandle, pOpenHandle, const_cast<PCHAR>("test"), ChannelOpenEventFn);
    return true;
}
```

4. Created the following server code

```
WTSVirtualChannelOpenEx(WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, "test", 0);
```

5. Connected to the server using remote desktop
6. Run the server executable

Despite this, the server still says it is an invalid channel.

Any and all help is welcome, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried the [wtsapi](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/ac06e54a15e9a62443e400fffff190fb978ea586/Samples/Win7Samples/winbase/wtsapi) sample?

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT I couldn't find one that utilized virtual channels.

Comment: [Isn't this](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/ac06e54a15e9a62443e400fffff190fb978ea586/Samples/Win7Samples/winbase/wtsapi/tssysinf/server/SysInf_S.c#L143)? [Call pVirtualChannelOpen when you received the CHANNEL_EVENT_CONNECTED event](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/ac06e54a15e9a62443e400fffff190fb978ea586/Samples/Win7Samples/winbase/wtsapi/tssysinf/client/SysInf_C.c#L374).